# According to the standard PCI bus scan but the result is abnormal

Tags: c, operating-system, qemu, pci, pci-bus

This is scanning code

```c
uint32_t pci_read_configd(uint8_t bus, uint8_t dev, uint8_t func, uint8_t offset)
{
    uint32_t address;
    uint32_t lbus  = (uint32_t)bus;
    uint32_t ldev = (uint32_t)dev;
    uint32_t lfunc = (uint32_t)func;
    address = (uint32_t)((lbus << 16) | (ldev << 11) |  (lfunc << 8) | (offset & 0xfc) | ((uint32_t)1 << 31));
    out_port32(0xcf8, address);
    return in_port32(0xcfc);
}

void init_pci(void)
{
    klog("pci","scanning device...");
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (size_t l = 0; l < 128; l++)
        {
                if(pci_read_configd(i,l,0,0) != 0xffff)
                {
                    klog("pci","found device at Bus.%h Dev.%h ID:%h BAR1:%h",i,l,pci_read_configd(i,l,0,0));
                }
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 0x3c; i+=4)
    {
        klog("pci","%h at %h" ,pci_read_configd(0,3,0,i),i);
    }
    
    klog("pci","OK");
}
```

this is the real pci device info (by qemu monitor)

```
(qemu) info pci
  Bus  0, device   0, function 0:
    Host bridge: PCI device 8086:1237
      id ""
  Bus  0, device   1, function 0:
    ISA bridge: PCI device 8086:7000
      id ""
  Bus  0, device   1, function 1:
    IDE controller: PCI device 8086:7010
      BAR4: I/O at 0xc040 [0xc04f].
      id ""
  Bus  0, device   1, function 3:
    Bridge: PCI device 8086:7113
      IRQ 9.
      id ""
  Bus  0, device   2, function 0:
    VGA controller: PCI device 1234:1111
      BAR0: 32 bit prefetchable memory at 0xfd000000 [0xfdffffff].
      BAR2: 32 bit memory at 0xfebf0000 [0xfebf0fff].
      BAR6: 32 bit memory at 0xffffffffffffffff [0x0000fffe].
      id ""
  Bus  0, device   3, function 0:
    Ethernet controller: PCI device 8086:100e
      IRQ 11.
      BAR0: 32 bit memory at 0xfebc0000 [0xfebdffff].
      BAR1: I/O at 0xc000 [0xc03f].
      BAR6: 32 bit memory at 0xffffffffffffffff [0x0003fffe].
      id ""
```

This is the result of PCI bus0 dev3 func0 manual scanning

```
[0x00000000]pci:scanning device...
[0x00000000]pci:found device at Bus.0x00000000Dev.0x00000000
[0x00000000]pci:found device at Bus.0x00000000Dev.0x00000001
[0x00000000]pci:found device at Bus.0x00000000Dev.0x00000002
[0x00000000]pci:found device at Bus.0x00000000Dev.0x00000003
[0x00000000]pci:0x00008086at 0x00000000
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000103at 0x00000004
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000003at 0x00000008
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x0000000C
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000010
[0x00000000]pci:0x0000C001at 0x00000014
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000018
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x0000001C
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000020
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000024
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000028
[0x00000000]pci:0x00001AF4at 0x0000002C
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000030
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000034
[0x00000000]pci:0x00000000at 0x00000038
[0x00000000]pci:OK
```

out_port32 is an encapsulation of outl instructions
in_port32 is the same

I found one thing, every time I read in, I can only read one WORD(is it helpful?)

But according to the PCI standard, there is no problem with such code implementation

I also used the sample code of OSDEV Wiki
The problem still exists
https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI

If you have any questions about other codes, you can visit github: LithiumOS-Team Lithium-OS

> Thank you for your any help

Comment: For `for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)` there are up to 256 buses so this should be `for (size_t bus = 0; bus < 256; bus++)`; and for `for (size_t l = 0; l < 128; l++)` there are only 32 devices per bus so this should be `for (size_t device = 0; device < 32; device++)`.  Using a "higher than possible" device number will trash the "bus number" field in the address calculation (in the `(uint32_t)((lbus << 16) | (ldev << 11) | ...`).

Comment: It's also not handling multi-function devices properly yet. For that you need to check if the device's "function 0" says it's a multi-function device, and only then check if functions 1 to 7 exist. Without that (with the code you have) it won't find 2 of the things (the IDE controller and bridge) listed by Qemu (as they're other functions in the same multi-function device).

Comment: sorry , actually all codes are right. the out_port32 function include inw command wrongly